# List function with Y combinator does no recursion, why?

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket, y-combinator, anonymous-recursion

Note: This is kind of homework, kind of not -- the end goal is to have a function that produces a powerset of a set of numbers supplied to the function as a list of numbers. I have a recursive version of the function but I now need to find some ways of replacing each explicitly recursive function in the solution I have (`append`, `mapm` etc.) with an equivalent lambda-only expression.

As such, I am starting with smaller problems and hope to combine them all to write a full function. I've managed to come up with a non-recursive factorial function using pure-lambda (Y combinator) but I am now trying to come up with a nice function that squares every number in a list -- trying to solve smaller problems before jumping up to a multiply-recursive function:

```
(define (sqrlist numlist)
  (((lambda (f)
   ((lambda (x) (x x))
    (lambda (g)
     (f (lambda (x) ((g g) x))))))
  (lambda (f)
   (lambda (x)
    (cons (sqr (first x)) (rest x))))) numlist))
```

The code above doesn't recurse, despite the presence of the Y combinator before it -- I'm obviously having some issues passing the proper parameters to the functions within -- any ideas?

Comment: Solved! Can I delete this question?

Comment: If you've solved it, can you post the answer here (or on your original question?) It's a pretty interesting question and answer IMHO.

Comment: Hi, I'd love to but my profs are pretty strict about posting code publicly until past the deadline.. I can email you a file with it though (the deadline isn't until Tuesday night. Also, I should clarify that my solution isn't for the whole problem... yet - it's just for the function I created above...

Comment: yes, `(lambda (f) (lambda (x) (cons (sqr (first x)) (rest x))))` does not use `f`. it should have been `(lambda (f) (lambda (x) (cons (sqr (first x)) (f   (rest x))   )))`, for it to recurse.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a working procedure, converting to anonymous procedures is relatively straightforward and mechanical. Give each lambda an extra argument, which is "itself", and duplicate the procedure. So

```
(define (add-list list) 
  (if (empty? list) 
      0 
      (+ (first list) (add-list (rest list)))))
```

Becomes

```
(λ(list) (if (empty? list) 0 (+ (first list) (add-list (rest list)))))
```

This is of course a problem because `add-list` isn't defined. So we're going to have to ensure that we pass *ourselves* around every time.

```
(λ(self list) (if (empty? list) 0 (+ (first list) (self self (rest list)))))
```

But where do we get ourselves in the first place? Well, we copy and paste (and give it an argument)

```
((λ(self list) (if (empty? list) 0 (+ (first list) (self self (rest list)))))
 (λ(self list) (if (empty? list) 0 (+ (first list) (self self (rest list)))))
 '(1 2 3 4))
```

Abstracting this "copy and paste" to the **Y** combinator is developed excellently in ["The Why of Y" <sup>(PDF)</sup>](https://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/WhyOfY.pdf) and you should definitely check it out.

But remember the first step was "get it working." Do this *before* you abstract away `define`s.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible answer, I know that you solved it already, but it could be useful to have a second opinion :)

```
((lambda (X)
    ((lambda (proc)
       (proc proc))
     (lambda (proc)
       (X (lambda (arg)
            ((proc proc) arg))))))
  (lambda (sqrlist)
    (lambda (lst)
      (if (null? lst)
          '()
          (cons (* (car lst) (car lst))
                (sqrlist (cdr lst)))))))
```

It's "lambda-only" since it's written exclusively in terms of anonymous functions, it doesn't even use `define`. Here's how to call it:

```
(((lambda (X)
     ((lambda (proc)
        (proc proc))
      (lambda (proc)
        (X (lambda (arg)
             ((proc proc) arg))))))
   (lambda (sqrlist)
     (lambda (lst)
       (if (null? lst)
           '()
           (cons (* (car lst) (car lst))
                 (sqrlist (cdr lst)))))))
 '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Comment: Nice! Now how can I further abstract that to take two parameters... say I wanted to cons all squared values in one list to all squared values in another list... without using append :D

Comment: I basically now am trying to write a non-recursive version of the append function.. Problem is, i'm trying to pass it two parameters and no-go.

Comment: For more than one parameter things might be a bit trickier. Perhaps by using currying?

Comment: ! I got it without resorting to currying! (Thank god, it's so messy already!) Take a peek:

`(define (my-append3 lst1 lst2)
  (((lambda (f)
    ((lambda (x) (x x))
     (lambda (g)
       (f (lambda (x) ((g g) x))))))
    (lambda (f)
      (lambda (x)
        (cond
          [(empty? x) lst2]
          [else (cons  (first x) (f(rest x)))]))))lst1))`

Comment: Excelent! I hope that you can share the code after your homework is done and graded