# Generating powerset in one function, no explicit recursion, and using only simplest primitives in Racket

Tags: lambda, scheme, lisp, racket, anonymous-recursion

**Note:** this is a bonus for homework, but I have spent way too long on trying things to no avail. Help is much appreciated, but not necessary I suppose.

**Premise:**
generate a powerset for a list of numbers, but without using any helpers, explicit recursion, looping, or functions/constants other than `cons`, `first`, `rest`, `empty?`, `empty`, `else`, `lambda`, and `cond`, while using only one `define` on the language level `Intermediate Student with Lambda`. The order of the powerset does not matter.

**What I've tried so far:**
I have discovered the Y-combinator and anonymous recursion thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260485/non-recursive-list-function-with-y-combinator) (author has the same end goal but we have different approaches, so the information in his post does not solve my problem), and the `powerset` code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623487/849891), and with that I have written the following:

```
(define (powerset aL)
  (((lambda (X)
      ((lambda (proc)
         (proc proc))
       (lambda (proc)
         (X (lambda (arg)
              ((proc proc) arg))))))
    (lambda (subset)
      (lambda (lst)
        (cond
          [(empty? lst) (list empty)]
          [else (combine (first aL) (powerset (rest aL)))])))) aL)

(define (combine a r)
  (cond
    [(empty? r)  empty]
    [else (cons (cons a (first r)) (cons (first r) (combine a (rest r))))]))
```

I'm testing this code by running:

```
(check-expect (powerset '(1 2 3)) 
(list '(1 2 3) '(2 3) '(1 3) '(3) '(1 2) '(2) '(1) '()))
```

This code runs and produces a correct result, but, as you can see, I still rely on an external helper function, `combine`, and I have no idea how to convert that into a `lambda` since to my knowledge, the Y-combinator only works with one parameter and `combine` needs 2. Perhaps my logic or approach to this problem is flawed. I have limited experience with `lambda` so I could be missing knowledge as well.

**What I need help with:** any suggestions as to next steps, helping me intergrate `combine` into `powerset`, providing hints/clues to correct logic/approach, or a solution would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally if you have solved your problem, you should say so with the Answer button: comments are not for answers. It's acceptable (even encouraged!) to answer your own questions. Just write the Answer that you would have liked to see someone else write.

Comment: I'm curious, did you get your original `powerset` code (the one before the conversion with the Y combinator) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623487/849891), or from somewhere else? (the transformation is wrong, BTW, the function set up by Y is not used, instead `powerset` is called by explicit recursion).

Comment: @amalloy professors are strict about code sharing, I'll share the code after the assignment is due!

Comment: Yes, I did take the logic from there since my original solution used `foldr` and `map` which would have been harder to replicate using anonymous recursion. I also realized that my code was using explicit recursion when writing the final version, I have corrected that mistake and the final code uses anonymous recursion with `lambda` only. Thanks for all the tips and answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the trick below easier to understand than using Y.  I think it's sort of related to U (which I also find easier to understand than Y).

It's possible that this isn't enough to meet the requirement of 'not being explicitly recursive', although I think it is.

If you have some function which 'wants' to use itself freely so it can recurse, such as:

```
(define powerset
  (λ (set)
    (cond [(empty? set)
           (list empty)]
          [else
           (combine (first set)
                    (powerset (rest set)))])))
```

Then you can turn that into a function which takes an additional argument, which it calls:

```
(define powerset/c
  (λ (ps/c set)
    (cond [(empty? set)
           (list empty)]
          [else
           (combine (first set)
                    (ps/c ps/c (rest set)))])))
```

The `/c` names are because when I discovered this trick I was thinking about the argument as a continuation, but I think that's because I didn't know what continuations were really.

And now (with a definition for `combine`), `(powerset/c powerset/c '(x y z))` will compute the power set of `(x y z)`, and there is no explicit recursion.

Well, that's ugly but this is easy to fix using

```
(define powerset
  (λ (set)
    ((λ (powerset/c)
       (powerset/c powerset/c set))
     (λ (ps/c set)
       (cond [(empty? set)
              (list empty)]
             [else
              (combine (first set)
                       (ps/c ps/c (rest set)))])))))
```

Then the trick is to write `combine` this way as well, and then use it locally, with

```
(define powerset
  (λ (set)
    ((λ (combine)
       ((λ (powerset/c)
          (powerset/c powerset/c set))
        (λ (ps/c set)
          (cond [(empty? set)
                 (list empty)]
                [else
                 (combine (first set)
                          (ps/c ps/c (rest set)))]))))
     <combine defn here>)))
```

Comment: yeah the whole purpose of **Y** is to spare one having to write `(f f x)` explicitly for a recursive call, nothing more (I think). too bad they don't say as much in the books, making it so complex instead, when it is really pretty simple.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8344517/849891) on the entry linked by OP in the Q, presents the same idea nicely.

Answer (score 4):

> the Y-combinator only works with one parameter and combine needs 2

Any multi-argument function can be imagined as a one-argument function, returning a lambda that waits for the next argument. This process is called currying. For example, if we have

```
(define add (x y)
  (+ x y))
```

we could call it like

```
(add 2 2)
```

Simple enough. Now let's curry it:

```
(define (add x)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ x y)))
```

Calling it takes a slightly different syntax, but it's the same basic idea:

```
((add 2) 2)
```

You can apply the same concept to any lambda if you wish to make it suitable to the Y combinator.

Answer (score 2):

In lambda calculus, all functions are curried unary functions.

This means

```
(define (combine a r)
  (cond
    [(empty? r)  empty]
    [else (cons (cons a (first r))
                (cons (first r) 
                      (combine a (rest r))))]))
```

would be written as

```
(λ (combine)
  (λ (a)
    (λ (r)
      (cond
        [(empty? r) empty]
        [else (cons (cons a (first r))
                    (cons (first r) 
                          ((combine a) (rest r))))]))))
```

With this in mind, here is the solution:

```
(define powerset
  ((λ (y)
     ((λ (f) (y (λ (x) ((f f) x))))
      (λ (f) (y (λ (x) ((f f) x))))))
   
   (λ (ps)
     (λ (set)
       (cond
         [(empty? set) (cons empty empty)]
         [else ((((λ (y)
                    ((λ (f) (y (λ (x) ((f f) x))))
                     (λ (f) (y (λ (x) ((f f) x))))))
                  
                  (λ (combine)
                    (λ (a)
                      (λ (r)
                        (cond
                          [(empty? r) empty]
                          [else (cons (cons a (first r))
                                      (cons (first r) 
                                            ((combine a) (rest r))))])))))
                 (first set))
                (ps (rest set)))])))))
```

Comment: "`(define (combine a r) ...)` would be written as" `(` **`Y`** `(λ (combine) (λ (a) (λ (r)  .... ))))`, though. as you indeed do, later in the answer. :)